# Diffrence between user and user_id in get() functions [Django]

Tags: django

UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)

these two line of codes are returning the same object. so what is the diffrence between them ?

Comment: First of all you haven't shared the `UserProfile` model, and secondly there is no difference between them, in first case `get(user=request.user)` it matches the user with request.user instance, it by default matches with id, in second case `get(user_id=request.user.id)` it also matches with id in the database, but here you are explicitly trying to match it with id, whereas first case, already contains the instance as a numeric value in the original db.

Comment: So is there a special case where we use user_id instead of user ? The UserProfile model is not important because it contains the user as a foreign key with the user name nothing else.

Comment: There are scenarios where you also might just have the id of a user and need to use get(user_id = id)  to grab the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the raw SQL queries that Django generates using `.query` on the queryset. If you compete filtering by `user=request.user` and `user_id=request.user.id` you will see that the SQL is the same.